# How to make small password reset token in asp.net web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, websecurity

I was sending password reset token in user's email with the default GeneratePasswordResetToken method but it was quite big like 200 to 300 characters long. I want to make smaller tokens like 5/6 digits long and expire it's life span within 3 minutes. How can I do that?

Comment: Any particular reason? Presumably you're sending it as part of a link, so the user doesn't need to type it, right? Also, 3 minutes seems very short - what if their email client only syncs 15 minutes?

Comment: And yes, 3 minutes may be too short for the email to even *arrive* at the client's SMTP server.

Comment: Yes. I don't want to send it through link. Because I have angular as my frontend. The user have to copy the token and paste it in another form.

Comment: What's the point? That's no kind of confirmation. It doesn't use a *different* channel, which is the whole point.

Comment: If I use the link that directly calls the backend. I want to generate the that calls the front end. Then the front end will call the back end. But I was failed to generate a link in web api that calls the front end app. That is why I want to do this approach.

Comment: That's equivalent to *no* confirmation at all. I could open the browser, ask to reset the password for some account and proceed without the real user ever knowing what happened. There's a reason confirmation messages are sent using different channels like emails or SMS. It's something the attacker *doesn't* have (we hope)

Comment: Then what will be the best thing to do? I have to send some sort of code into user's email.

Comment: Are you trying to implement something like Medium's or Slack's passwordless authentication? Check [Implementing Medium's Passwordless Authentication using ASP.NET Core Identity](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Implementing-Mediums-Passwordless-Authentication-using-ASPNET-Core-Identity) and [Implementing custom token providers for passwordless authentication in ASP.NET Core Identity](https://andrewlock.net/implementing-custom-token-providers-for-passwordless-authentication-in-asp-net-core-identity/)

Comment: `into user's email.` that's not what you asked in the *comments*. You asked for something that would be sent to the browser. There's *nothing* wrong with the current token, in fact the link *should* stay the way it is - that token is unique, encrypted and signed to ensure it's not hijacked and can't be replayed

Comment: In any case, the tokens are generated by providers and the articles I point to show how you can create your own. [The base class](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85f8a49aef68bf9763cd9854ce1dd4a26a7c5d3c/src/Core/TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider.cs) generates token values and then it encrypts and signs them with `Rfc6238AuthenticationService.GenerateCode`. You could create your own provider that used weaker or no encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be like this:

Have a table in your database where you save the reset tokens and their creation datetime.

When a user requests a reset, generate a GUID and save it in that table, then send an email to the user containing a reset link with the token already included.

When the user clicks the link, you check that the token has not expired already and if it hasn't then allow them to change their password.

Once the password has been changed, either mark the token as already used, or simply delete it from your table.

GUIDs are good for this kind of functionality, they are unique enough and impossible to guess.

DO NOT go with anything sequential, or short ( 5, 6 characters ) as those are easy to guess / brute force.

Comment: I was thinking the same.